# How to create user in cisco ucs manager from api?

Tags: devops, cisco

I use cisco usc manager emulator and need add new local user (using ansible). I read about uscmsdk for python and XML api. But i can't find where is user section on both of them. Is it any method there to do this? https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/unified_computing/ucs/sw/api/b_ucs_api_book/b_ucs_api_book_chapter_010.html#topic_B19A7BEBFBAB4DDFB90B9456709C6402

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So simply we have 3 ways to do this:

1. Use XML api with configConfMo method
2. Use [uscmsdk](https://github.com/CiscoUcs/ucsmsdk) with ucsmsdk/mometa/aaa/AaaUser module
3. Use ansible [ucs_managed_objects](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/ucs_managed_objects_module.html) (prefer way in my situation).